# Auto Increment ID break the Sequence

Tags: java, mysql

My program has an auto incremented ID with the format of `ITM001, ITM002...`. But after `ITM009, ITM0010` the sequence is broken and goes back to `ITM001`. Because of that I'm getting `ITM0010` as next item ID instead of `ITM0011`. Please help me to understand how should I write the query to continue the sequence.

```
ITM001
**ITM0010**
ITM002
ITM003
ITM004
ITM005
ITM006
ITM007
ITM008
ITM009
```

```
   Connection conn = DBConnection.conn();
      String sql = "select itemId from ItemMain";
       ResultSet res = DBHandller.getData(sql, conn);
        if (res.last()) {
              String lastid = res.getString("itemId");
               return lastid;
        }
        return null;   
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


              String itemID = ItemController.getItemID();

              String[] split = itemID.split("ITM",0);
              int num = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
              itemID = "ITM00"+ (num+1);
              txtitemID.setText(itemID);
```

Comment: If you need a gap-less sequence, auto-increment is just the wrong tool for the job. Whatever, it isn't immediately clear how you use auto-increment here since your column appears to be VARCHAR :-?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario yes. itemId is varchar. Do you have any idea how can i get the sequence of Item ids.

Comment: You are actually *not* talking about MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature, are you?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario no. I tried to get the last ID from table then use SPLIT function to get the value of number part and add 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `split` on 0, and there are several 0's in your String after you increment, for instance:

```
    String[] split = itemID.split("ITM",0);
    int num = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
    String second = "ITM00" + (num + 1);
    System.out.println(second);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(second.split("0")));
```

This will output:

```
[ITM, , 1]
```

Since the last 0 will also be split.

Something like:

```
String itemID = "ITM009";
int num = Integer.parseInt(itemID.substring(itemID.indexOf("0")));
String second = "ITM0" + String.format("%02d", num + 1);
System.out.println(second);
```

Will give you what you want probably, but you need to figure out how many digits you want your key to have and adapt accordingly.

Comment: I see. Thnx for your suggestion. Let me try with that.

Comment: See my update, it's a simpler approach that will probably achieve what you want.

Comment: Thnx so much. I ll try with that. Thnx again.

Comment: its works fine with "ITM0". But still getting same problem when I used format ITM00. Could you help me to fix? pls

Comment: I would advise you to specify a minimum length for your key... if you want 0 as the separator, the first would be ITM000, if you want your first 0 to be significant, then you need to adjust the sub-string.

Comment: thnx I got it. I changed the substring

Answer (score 0):

You are implicitly sorting on a VARCHAR field.

```
SELECT a.a FROM (
    SELECT 'a001' [a]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a009' [a]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a0010' [a]
) a ORDER BY a

a001
a0010
a009
```

The last id you pick up will always be 009 so the next one you create will always be 0010.

If you front padded the "10" with 1 "0" instead of two the implicit ascending sorting would be correct. "001 ... 009, 010"